# Python: docstrings and type annotations

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Having a function like:

```
def foo(x: int) -> float:
    return float(x)
```

I would like to use a NumPy-like docstring like the following:

```
def foo(x: int) -> float:
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    x
        Input parameter

    Returns
    -------
    The output value.
    """
    return float(x)
```

Note that:

- I do not want to specify the parameter type again.
- I do not want to specify the return type again.
- I would like that extension to be able to read the annotated types (and write them in the generated HTML documentation).

Is there a Sphinx extension that supports that? Would you recommend another syntax?

Comment: I'm not seeing why downvote.  I mean you could read it as asking for a tool, but you could also answer the question as "given that I have sphinx documentation, how do I get this into the docs?"

Comment: I know that mypy allows you to specify argument and return types and will raise exceptions or alerts during run time if a type is different to what you have defined. Don't know if this info helps.

Answer (score 3):

Standard extension is [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html). [Napoleon](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html) extension supports Google- and NumPy-style docstrings.

Comment: Napoleon does support NumPy-style docstrings, but for what I have seen, it expects a return type in the docstring, right? (which is something I would like to avoid)

Comment: No, [Sphinx can infer return type](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html#type-annotations) from annotations.

Comment: Maybe it can, but when generating the documentation I still see an empty "Return type" field when using NumPy docstrings. Also, parameters and return types are displayed in the documentation only in the function fingerprint, not in the actual parameter description nor the return description. Have you tried yourself to see if you get the expected output?

Comment: 5 years later and this solution is only half-way there. Napoleon supports those style docstrings, but the annotated types do not end up in the parameter or returns section. Instead, they are in the function call signature, which is then unreadable if there are long types or more than a couple parameters. Since call signatures are just one long line in the docs, they're actually easier to read in the original source. Pretty disappointing. Any alternatives that work better?